# Manipulating the case of the build macros in Visual Studio: $(TargetDir)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I've come across a weird problem today in Visual Studio 2005.  If I create a new configuration "NewConfiguration" for one of my projects.  The output directory referred to by the project in $(TargetDir) is "/path/to/build/area/newconfiguration".  Note the loss of capital letters, I'd expect it to be in "/path/to/build/area/NewConfiguration".  In another project that I created yesterday, the capital letters are there.  Normally this would be a problem, but it's part of a fairly complicated build system where some of it's on unix and we need to worry about case sensitive filename.  Does anyone know where the source string for the Visual Studio macros like $(TargetDir) are stored so that I can get the case to be consistent and match what we need for our build system?